# Is it possible to mathematically calculate residual heparin present in circulation , used in neurointervention?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

In Neurointervention, 5000 I.U of Heparin is initially given as a loading dose at the time of starting a procedure (t= 0) and 1000 I.U dose is repeated in each subsequent hours (t = 1 hour). Left us suppose the effective half life of heparin is 1.5 hours. How can we calculate residual heparin present inside body after "X" hours?    (I.U = International Units).

If an explicit equation can be formed containing only X , it will help neurointerventionists to calculate the antidote to be given after the procedure.

Comment: You can solve this using [exponential decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay). Split the problem into several decays, one for each time the patient is receiving heparin with the initial condition of the heparin present at the time + the newly received heparin as a boundary condition.